# Is there a way to "source" a sh script from the fish shell?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, sh, fish

I like to put many of my environment variable definitions in the `.profile` script. If I am using a POSIX-compatible interactive shell like bash, I can use the source command to re-export the environment variables from `.profile` when it gets updated, without needing to open a new terminal window. Is there a way to do the same when I am using `fish`, which uses a different syntax for exporting variables? **Can I tell fish to run a `sh` subproccess and reexport any variables it defines?**

When I try doing the obvious `sh .profile` the environment variables apparently only get defined in the child `sh` process and don't get updated in the parent `fish` process.

---

edit: the shell code defining my variables is this one

```
CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/hugo/.opam/4.01.0/lib/stublibs"; export CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
PERL5LIB="/home/hugo/.opam/4.01.0/lib/perl5:"; export PERL5LIB;
OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH="/home/hugo/.opam/4.01.0/lib/toplevel"; export OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH;
MANPATH=":/home/hugo/.opam/4.01.0/man"; export MANPATH;
PATH="/home/hugo/.opam/4.01.0/bin:/home/hugo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"; export PATH;
```

Unfortunately, this code is automatically generated by another program, so the conversion to Fish must also be made using an automated process. I tried using the following sed script

```
sed 's/\(.*\)="\(.*\)".*/set -x \1 \'\2\';/'
```

which outputs the following Fish code

```
set -x CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH '/home/hugo/.opam/4.01.0/lib/stublibs';
set -x PERL5LIB '/home/hugo/.opam/4.01.0/lib/perl5:';
set -x OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH '/home/hugo/.opam/4.01.0/lib/toplevel';
set -x MANPATH ':/home/hugo/.opam/4.01.0/man';
set -x PATH '/home/hugo/.opam/4.01.0/bin:/home/hugo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games';
```

Which I can run using eval and `()` substitution

```
eval (my-sed-script)
```

However, fish is complaining when I try to set PATH. I think it might be special-casing PATH and expecting an array instead of a single string.

```
set: Warning: path component /home/hugo/.opam/4.01.0/bin:/home/hugo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /home/hugo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games'?
```

Comment: No you cannot. A child process cannot alter the environment of its parent.

Show the format of your .profile. We can probably translate it into valid fish syntax, the result can be `eval`ed

Comment: @glennjackman: aw, that sucks. I edited the question to add the extra information you asked for. Right now I still need to figure out how to set PATH in fish and how to integrate that into the sed script.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For sourcing a general `sh` script in `fish`, one option is the [bass](https://github.com/edc/bass) plugin, which can source a bash script's environment variables into fish.

If you have [fisherman](https://github.com/fisherman/fisherman), you can install it with `fisher install edc/bass`, then run `bass source <command>`.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike bash, the fish PATH is an array of directories: 
http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#variables

```
sed '/^PATH=/s/:/\' \'/g; s/\(.*\)="\(.*\)".*/set -x \1 \'\2\';/'
```